# How to place click event on each table row and pass result as argument to bind new data to another source?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have the following code which populates a `select options` and passes the selected value to another function in the view model which populates a table with data matching the selected value:

In a nutshell, if the user selects ASIA from the select option, all countries in ASIA are bind to the table:

[Fiddle Example here:](https://jsfiddle.net/L23fk7fp/4/)

How do I add a click event to each row in the table so that I can pass the `CountryId` of the row clicked as argument to another function in the `View Model`? I need to use the argument and function to perform additional bindings. E.g.: `Country Detail`.

This is what I have so far:

```
<div id="country-select">
    <select data-bind="options: UniqueContinent,
                       value: SelectedContinent"></select>
</div>

<table id="country-list">
    <tr>
        <th>CountryID</th>
        <th>Country Name</th>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>Continent</th>
        <th>CountryAbbr</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody data-bind= "foreach: FilteredEntries">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: CountryId"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Country"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: City"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: Continent"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: CountryAbbr"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

*JS Code:*

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.CountryData = ko.observableArray([
  {
    "City": "KABUL",
    "Continent": "ASIA",
    "Country": "AFGHANISTAN",
    "CountryAbbr": "AF",
    "CountryId": "102120"
  },
   {
    "City": "DHAKA",
    "Continent": "ASIA",
    "Country": "BANGLADESH",
    "CountryAbbr": "BD",
    "CountryId": "102136"
  },       
  {
    "City": "BRUSSELS",
    "Continent": "EUROPE",
    "Country": "BELGIUM",
    "CountryAbbr": "BE",
    "CountryId": "102139"
  },
  {
    "City": "MINSK",
    "Continent": "EUROPE",
    "Country": "BELARUS",
    "CountryAbbr": "BY",
    "CountryId": "102138"
  }]);

    self.SelectedContinent = ko.observable('');

    self.UniqueContinent = ko.dependentObservable(function() {
        var continent = ko.utils.arrayMap(self.CountryData(),

            function(item){

                return item.Continent
            })

        return ko.utils.arrayGetDistinctValues(continent).sort();
    });

    // Call this function when changes are made
    self.FilteredEntries = ko.computed(function() {

        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.CountryData(), function(item) {
            // I need to use the selected value
            return item.Continent === self.SelectedContinent();
        });
    });
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a `click` handler to your `<tr>`:

```
<tr data-bind="click: $root.CountryDetails">
```

And in your script:

```
self.CountryDetails = function(country)
{
    doSomethingWithCountryId(country.CountryId);
}

function doSomethingWithCountryId(countryId)
{
    // ...
}
```

See updated [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L23fk7fp/5/) and [Documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html)